# How do I check read write execute permission from the subdirectories?

Tags: shell, permissions, ksh

Let say I have a folder "football" and in the football folder, it contains 4 folders Chelsea, United, Liverpool and Spurs. Each sub folder in football folder has different permission for read, write and execute.... Now how would I get the value for read, write and execute? If the folder is readable, print "can read" and so on.....Is it possible to check with the 775,777 something like this?

```
 #!/bin/ksh
 for d in [subfolder]
 do
    if [subfolder can read == $permission_read ]
       printf "Can read"
     else if.........................
     else
            .........................
      fi
  done
```

subfolder is supposed to pass Chelsea, United, Liverpool and Spurs to check for every permission.....

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following solution.

```
cat script.ksh
GET_PERM() {
cate="$1"
element_to_check="$2"
directory="$directory"

case "$element_to_check" in
"7") echo "Directory named $directory has READ/WRITE/EXECUTE permissions for $cate.";;
"6") echo "Directory named $directory has READ/WRITE permissions for $cate.";;
"5") echo "Directory named $directory has READ/EXECUTE permissions for $cate.";;
"4") echo "Directory named $directory has READ permissions for $cate.";;
"3") echo "Directory named $directory has WRITE/EXECUTE permissions for $cate.";;
"2") echo "Directory named $directory has WRITE permissions for $cate.";;
"1") echo "Directory named $directory has EXECUTE permissions for $cate.";;
"0") echo "Directory named $directory has NULL permissions for $cate.";;
*) echo "Please check Directory named $directory has "$element_to_check" permission.";;
esac
}


while read directory
do
  echo "$directory"
  perm=($(stat -c "%a" "$directory" | awk 'length($0)>3{gsub(/./,"& ");print substr($0,3);next} {gsub(/./,"& ");print}'))
  echo "${perm[*]}"
  for i in "${perm[@]}"
  do
    ((count = count + 1))
    if [[ $count -eq 1 ]]
    then
        GET_PERM "USER/OWNER" "$i" "$directory"
    elif [[ $count -eq 2 ]]
    then
        GET_PERM "GROUPS" "$i" "$directory"
    else
        GET_PERM "OTHERS" "$i" "$directory"
    fi
  done
  unset perm
  unset count
done < <(find -type d 2>/dev/null)
```

---

---

***What script does is:***

- It has `find` command in last of `while` loop which will run as per your given path(as of now no path given to it so it runs on current directory, one could mention complete path for which you want to check in it).
- It deals with basic permissions read, write and execute basic ones, though I know there could be many kind of permissions but I am going with OP's ask here.

---

---

Test run of above script: When I run above script for a test directory which has 3 directories named `test1`, `test2`,`test3` it gives following output.

```
.
7 7 5
Directory named . has READ/WRITE/EXECUTE permissions for USER/OWNER.
Directory named . has READ/WRITE/EXECUTE permissions for GROUPS.
Directory named . has READ/EXECUTE permissions for OTHERS.
./test3
7 5 5
Directory named ./test3 has READ/WRITE/EXECUTE permissions for USER/OWNER.
Directory named ./test3 has READ/EXECUTE permissions for GROUPS.
Directory named ./test3 has READ/EXECUTE permissions for OTHERS.
./test1
7 7 5
Directory named ./test1 has READ/WRITE/EXECUTE permissions for USER/OWNER.
Directory named ./test1 has READ/WRITE/EXECUTE permissions for GROUPS.
Directory named ./test1 has READ/EXECUTE permissions for OTHERS.
./test2
7 4 4
Directory named ./test2 has READ/WRITE/EXECUTE permissions for USER/OWNER.
Directory named ./test2 has READ permissions for GROUPS.
Directory named ./test2 has READ permissions for OTHERS.
```

Answer (score 0):

Using shell commands we can see the rwx permissions of sub-directories.

Suppose there is directory structure a/b/c/d. To know rwx permissions just execute below command:

```
ls -l -R a
```

it will print the details for all sub-directories inside directory a.

You can stream out the output and save it in some file, and same you can parse to know the rwx details of sub-directories.

```
ls -l -R a > file.txt
cat file.txt
```

Check the attached screenshots for reference.

[image]
[image]